# VBA Record reading limitation?

Tags: excel, vba, dao

I am using Excel 2016 VBA to read an Access 2016 database using the DAO references. I’m doing this, because it is much easier to create dynamic form controls in Excel. It seemed to work fine, but I just found out it only reads the first 335 records of any table, even if I constrain three record set with an SQL query.

I started with the following to read a table of racks in a room:

```
DIM db as DAO.Database

DIM rsRacks as DAO.Recordset

DIM strSQL as String

‘Initialization code deleted

StrSQL = “SELECT * FROM tblRacks WHERE RoomID = “ & str(RoomID) & _
  “ ORDER BY RackName”

Set rsRacks = db.openrecordset(strSQL)
```

It didn’t read three racks I added to the table so I altered the code to

```
Set rsRacks = db.openrecordset(“tblRacks”)

Debug.print rsracks.recordcount
```

The immediate window reported

> 335

The table has over a thousand rack records. Any ideas?

Comment: Please format your code with `codeblocks`

Comment: [`RecordCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-recordcount-property-dao) is the number of records *accessed*, not necessarily *returned*. Are you iterating the records?

Comment: Thanks for the input, Mathieu, but I found the problem. I had an artifact in my code from a previous version and it was reading the wrong database.

Answer (score 0):

Despite your comment about accessing the wrong database, it is actually possible that the `RecordCount` of a freshly opened recordset is wrong.

It explicitly says in the [DAO docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-recordcount-property-dao) that the `RecordCount` is the number of "accessed" (actually of already-read / buffered) rows. Only when you have read the whole recordset i.e. by `MoveNext` or `MoveLast` method, you can rely on the `RecordCount`.

Usually this problem likes to bite you when switching from a development database with some 100 test records to a much larger production database.